# FullCalendar end date null whenever event is not changed even though allday false

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Does anybody know why is the end date null on those "allday=false" events?

Fiddle Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/L1g0z3jd/

I instantiate it differently from the start date, it shows just fine in the calendar view, but for some reason I can't understand whenever i get clientEvents, even thought i have not changed it, I got a null in the event end date!

PS: Just for the sake of "conscience" I must add ... I'm using and old version of google chrome (v 57.0.2987.133 64-bit) and an old ubuntu version (Linux Mint 18.1 Serena)

Its getting me crazy! Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<button onclick="javascript:getEvents()">Get Events</button>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    visibleRange: {start: moment('2000-01-02'), end: moment('2000-01-09')},
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    views: {
        settimana: {
            type: 'agenda',
            columnFormat: 'ddd',
            hiddenDays: []
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'settimana',
    defaultDate: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('week'),
    slotMinutes: 30,
    events: [
                $.fn.getAgendaWorktime(1, "08:00:00", 60),
                $.fn.getAgendaWorktime(2, "08:30:00", 120),
            ],
    select: function(startDate, endDate) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: 'free time',
            start: startDate.format(),
            end: endDate.format(),
            allDay: false
        });
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log(calEvent, jsEvent, view);
        if(doubleClick==calEvent._id){
            if (confirm('Delete it?')) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent._id);
            }
            doubleClick = null;
        }else{
            doubleClick=calEvent._id;
        }
    },
});
});
function getEvents() {
    var e=0,err=false,$data = []
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').forEach(periodo => {
        if (periodo.end==null || periodo.start.format().substr(0,10)!=periodo.end.format().substr(0,10)) {
            if (e==0) {
                err = true;
                e++;
                alert('Event startint at '+periodo.start.format()+' cant spread to multiple days');
            }
        } else {
            $data.push({'ini': periodo.start.format(), 'fim': periodo.end.format()});
        }
    });
    alert($data);
}

jQuery.fn.getAgendaWorktime = function ($dow, $start, $elapsed) {
    var r = {
        allDay: false,
        title: 'free time',
        start: new Date('2000-01-02 '+$start),
        end: new Date('2000-01-02 '+$start)
    };
    r.start.setDate(r.start.getDate()+$dow);
    r.end.setDate(r.end.getDate()+$dow);
    r.end.setHours(r.end.setHours()+($elapsed*60));
    return(r);
}
```

Comment: PS: it should show something else than an empty "string" in the second alert whenever clicking the "Get Events" button! It should show an array with two items inside instead and its not doing it for the "periodo.end" attribute is always null!

Comment: Because your formula for setting the end date is producing an invalid value. See https://jsfiddle.net/96278dgu/

Comment: Yes, i found that and explained that better in the answer below. Thanks for your help @ADyson

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to solve the question, I will reply to it here for I have not found any workaround or further analysis of the problem in the internet ....

I didn't review my problem to determine if it was specific related to the fact that I was setting the event's end time incorrectly and the calendar wasn't giving me any errors on the issue or anything else, but if you're gowing by the same road i went i can tell you:

1. Check to see if the end time is been created corretly (that seams to be my real mistaken, I was using setHours instead getHours in the getAgendaWorktime function, which turned the final value to be null. I corrected it in the sample below, but let it incorrectly in the fiddle to show the use of the forceEventDuration attribute);
2. Set "forceEventDuration" parameter to "true" (that forces the "end" attribute to always be filled easying me up in my code for I can always awaits for an string from ".format()" method of the attibute);

for meny reasons fullcalendar.io some times does not sets the event end date and this was getting me problems whenever avaluating the event end time (Ok, I could work around it but I was intrigged for why does it was getting me those results when it sould not, and the answare was a buged code). With "forceEventDuration: true" fullcalendar gave me the end time every time therefor i could find out that the input method i was using was seting the end date incorrectly and gave me the chance to correct it as well.

Links related:

- Calendar parameter documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/forceEventDuration
- Corrected Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gjrfox05/

I hope this answer could be of some  help for newcomers at fullcalendar.io as me.

Fiddle Javascript part corrected sample:

```
$(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    forceEventDuration: true,
    visibleRange: {start: moment('2000-01-02'), end: moment('2000-01-09')},
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    views: {
        settimana: {
            type: 'agenda',
            columnFormat: 'ddd',
            hiddenDays: []
        }
    },
    defaultView: 'settimana',
    defaultDate: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('week'),
    slotMinutes: 30,
    events: [
                $.fn.getAgendaWorktime(1, "08:00:00", 60),
                $.fn.getAgendaWorktime(2, "08:30:00", 120),
            ],
    select: function(startDate, endDate) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: 'free time',
            start: startDate.format(),
            end: endDate.format(),
            allDay: false
        });
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log(calEvent, jsEvent, view);
        if(doubleClick==calEvent._id){
            if (confirm('Delete it?')) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent._id);
            }
            doubleClick = null;
        }else{
            doubleClick=calEvent._id;
        }
    },
});
});
function getEvents() {
    var e=0,err=false,$data = []
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').forEach(periodo => {
        if (periodo.end==null || periodo.start.format().substr(0,10)!=periodo.end.format().substr(0,10)) {
            if (e==0) {
                err = true;
                e++;
                alert('Event startint at '+periodo.start.format()+' cant spread to multiple days');
            }
        } else {
            $data.push({'ini': periodo.start.format(), 'fim': periodo.end.format()});
        }
    });
    alert($data[0].fim);
}

jQuery.fn.getAgendaWorktime = function ($dow, $start, $elapsed) {
    var r = {
        allDay: false,
        title: 'free time',
        start: new Date('2000-01-02 '+$start),
        end: new Date('2000-01-02 '+$start)
    };
    r.start.setDate(r.start.getDate()+$dow);
    r.end.setDate(r.end.getDate()+$dow);
    r.end.setHours(r.end.getHours()+($elapsed*60));
    return(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default FullCalendar end date null when event end_date = start_date.

I Just pass another fiend with same date from database (Django View).

```
   event_sub_arr['end'] = end_date
    event_sub_arr['end_same_date'] = end_date
```

And check in javaScript

```
  eventClick: function(info) {
    var modal = document.getElementById('DeleteEventModal')
    getEventDeleteUrl(info.event.id)
    getEventUpdateUrl(info.event.id)
    modal.style.display = 'block'
    calendar.unselect()

    var start = info.event.start
    var end_same_date = info.event.end_same_date
    var end = info.event.end || end_same_date


    $("#event_id_name").text(info.event.title)
    $("#event_id_start").text(moment(start).format('h:mm:ss a, MMMM Do YYYY'))
    $("#event_id_end").text(moment(end).format('h:mm:ss a, MMMM Do YYYY'))
    console.log(info.event.start)
    console.log(info.event.end)
    console.log({{ event_data|safe }})

  },
```

ITS WORK FOR ME